# How to select records from Oracle Database where 2 dates are not in same month and year

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

How to select records from Oracle Database where 2 dates are not in same month and year.

Below table is example, here I want all records where created date and updated date are not in same month and year.

The value for both date field in millisecond (ex.1454738400000) and 
Data type of both date field is NUMBER(32).

```
---------------------------------
id| Created Date | Updated Date |
---------------------------------
1 | 02/26/2018   | 02/26/2017   |
---------------------------------
2 | 03/28/2018   | 03/26/2018   |
---------------------------------
3 | 04/26/2018   | 04/28/2017   |
---------------------------------
4 | 02/26/2018   | 02/26/2016   |
---------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at these two options:

```
select record_id
from your_table
where to_char(created_date, 'mm.yyyy') <> to_char(updated_date, 'mm.yyyy');

select record_id
from your_table
where trunc(created_date, 'yyyy') <> trunc(updated_date, 'yyyy')
  and trunc(created_date, 'mm')   <> trunc(updated_date, 'mm');
```

If there's a lot of data involved, consider creating a function-based index(es) on DATE columns.

**[EDIT]**

If those values really are numbers, then you have to convert them to DATE datatype first, then apply `TRUNC` function. For example:

```
SQL> select trunc(to_date(20190226, 'yyyymmdd'), 'yyyy') result from dual;

RESULT
----------
01.01.2019

SQL>
```

Note that it'll fail if format is wrong, for example 20190231 (which is supposed to be 31st of February 2019) as there aren't 31 days in February.

If possible, change those columns' datatype to DATE.

Comment: Thanks for help... Facing below error for both ORA-01481: invalid number format model 01481. 00000 -  "invalid number format model" *Cause:    The user is attempting to either convert a number to a string            via TO_CHAR or a string to a number via TO_NUMBER and has            supplied an invalid number format model parameter. *Action:   Consult your manual. ---------------------------------------------------------- `for 2nd `ORA-01722: invalid number 01722. 00000 -  "invalid number" *Cause:    The specified number was invalid. *Action:   Specify a valid number.

Comment: What is CREATED_DATE and UPDATED_DATE columns' datatype? Apparently, it is not a DATE (should be!).

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention Both are in number data type is NUMBER(32)

Comment: How do those values really look, then? You posted `04/26/2018`, and that is **not** a number.

Comment: Here is one example value 1454738400000

Comment: What does that number represent? Doesn't look like any date I know. By the way, I added some more info into the answer, have a look. Once you find out which format it is, you'll have to convert it to DATE.

Comment: Hey thanks... I converted that date milliseconds to Date format and your answer is working... Thanks again...!